# LotusNotes NotesStream to byte array /

Tags: .net, vb.net, com, stream, lotus-notes

I want to read the content of a NotesStream object (COM reference) without using the file system. Thus my intension was to transfer the content into a .NET byte array.
My examples are in VB.net because we needed late binding at that time.

The only way I managed to do it is by reading the stream byte by byte (assuming the Position in the stream was set to `0` beforehand):

```
Dim streamSize As Long = CInt(notesStream.Bytes)
Dim buffer(streamSizes - 1) As Byte

For i = 0 To (streamSize - 1)
    buffer(i) = notesStream.read(1)(0)
Next
```

This is very very slow compared to using the filesystem (`notesStream.Open()`).

The other solutions I found all gave me errors, like this 2 examples:

```
buffer = notesStream.Read(streamSize)
```

> -> error: the object of type "System.Byte[ * ]" cannot be converted to type "System.Byte[]"
>           / Unable To Cast Object Of Type "System.Byte[ * ]" To Type "System.Byte[]"

(without the additional space character between the brackets and the asterisk, but otherwise it wouldn't have benn displayed correctly in this post)

```
Array.Copy(notesStream.Read(), 0, buffer, 0, streamSize)
```

> -> error: Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.

Comment: if you do `object buffer = notesStream.Read(streamSize)`, what's the returned real type of `buffer`?

Comment: it's of type Byte(). If I then go on and use it e.g. in this statement "Using memStream As New MemoryStream(buffer, False)" I again get this exception:  the object of type "System.Byte[ * ]" cannot be converted to type "System.Byte[]"

Comment: can you do a `foreach(var byte in buffer)` on this buffer thing?

Comment: what would be the source code equivalent in VB.Net (assuming having "Option Infer" set to "On")? .. just to be sure to use the right syntax.
Would it be `For Each byte In buffer` (without mentioning the type at all) ?

Comment: Dim byte as Byte For Each byte In buffer

Comment: yes, I was able to do a foreach over the buffer object.
fyi: the code worked also by not using the beforehand 'Dim byte as Byte' (and thus using type inference .. if I'm right on this).

Comment: Can you try to do this `Dim arr As Array = DirectCast(application.Evaluate(name), Array)
`? Does it throw or does it succeed and get back 'something' in arr?